# Simplest way to open the URL in the .txt file using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, browser, command

Let's say I have a .txt file in the sample folder as shown in the path below:

```
C:\Users\Documents\sample\link.txt
```

Inside the link.txt, it has an URL to a website:

```
https://www.sample.com
```

Now, I'm looking for a way to open this URL in the .txt file using the PowerShell command.
Ideally, I can open the URL with Chrome using a command like:

```
PS C:\Users> chrome C:\Users\Documents\sample\link.txt
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2) Cmdlet to read the file contents and [`[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-process-start(system-string-system-string)) API to start the Chrome application.

So to answer your question you can do,

```
Get-Content urls.txt | ForEach-Object { 
   [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome", $_) 
}
```

Comment: `gc urls.txt | % { start $_ }` for short

Comment: @Thor 
Thanks, Thor. What about if you need to select the browser? My default browser is Chrome, but if I wanna use MS Edge to open the url, then do you know what I should do?

Comment: start is the alias for start-process, there you can also specify which process to start, e.g. ```start-process [pathToProgram] -argumentlist [uri]```